# SwiftUI - How to initialize only one SectionView in ScrollView using onTapGesture

Tags: swiftui

My problem is that when user presses on the item in my ScrollView all of the SectionView items changes. What I want to do is to change only one item. I'm trying to change item image when user taps on it and then when user taps on another item to bring back previous item image and change the current item image.

Take a look at my ScrollView:

```
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 15) {
                    ForEach(1..<41) { item in
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                            SectionView(number: item, pressed: pressed, firstElement: (item == 1) ? true : false)
                                .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees:
                                                            Double(geometry.frame(in: .global).minX - 30) / -20
                                ), axis: (x: 0, y: 10, z: 0))
                                
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    self.pressed.toggle()
                                    SectionView(number: item, pressed: self.pressed, firstElement: (item == 1) ? true : false)
                                    print("touched item \(item)")
                                }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here's my SectionView:

```
struct SectionView: View {
var number: Int
var pressed: Bool
var firstElement: Bool

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        Image(pressed ? "t1" : "t\(number)")
            .resizable()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        
        Spacer()
        
        Text(firstElement ? "" : "Pride")
            .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .black))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .padding(.bottom, 15)
    }
    .frame(width: 60, height: 80)
    //.background(section.image)
    .cornerRadius(7)
    //.shadow(color: section.image.opacity(0.15), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 10)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting your code into some kind of buildable state, but I couldn't get it to compile or run, so I may be completely misinterpreting what you are trying to do. However, it seems to me you are using `pressed` as if you are capturing the state at the time of the press on that particular `SectionView`. However, it would have to be a State var to compile, so it will update all of the views, which is what I believe you are seeing. I think what you need to do is change `pressed` to be an Int that keeps track of the `SectionView` that was pressed, and compare it to number which lets the particular `SectionView` keep track of its identity.

Also, I don't think you want the `SectionView` in the tap gesture. I think you just want to change the state of the pressed variable and let it work its way through the hierarchy.